# Currently learning and im curious if someone can explain what the difference between array = array.splice() and array.splice()

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

In the context of a function that takes in two arguments, (or parameters, idk when they are considered arguments and when they're considered parameters) an array and an index value. The goal of the challenge was to use the function to splice an array that is passed in using the index function variable like below:

```
function foo(array, index) {
    array.splice(index, 1)
    return array
}
```

This worked and passed the challenge, however when I first tried to run the below code using an equals sign before the array.splice() it did not work, see below:

```
function foo(array, index) {
    array = array.splice(index, 1)
    return array
}
```

As for what I was expecting I guess I was expecting either to work, but since it did not I am more curious as to why. A lot of times while I am trying to Javascript ill get errors, my code will be almost 100% find save for one error like the above where I add an equals in a spot it does not belong. What is happening under-the-hood in the above examples that make one work and not the other?

Also, if possible please explain when it is and is not appropriate to use an '=' sign. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: But here i think the best course is to read the documentation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice. The return value is not what you're assuming it to be.

Comment: As with anything like this, it really helps to read the docs.

Comment: When reading the documentation, keep in mind that the first snippet, `array.splice(index,1);return array;` does something with `array`, and returns `array` after that change. While the second snippet could be written as `someotherarray=array.splice(index,1);return someotherarray;`, so it returns what `splice()` returned and it's just a shortcut that you re-used an already existing variable. So it's not about being appropriate or inappropriate, the two functions simply do different things.

Comment: @tevemadar thank you for the explanation. This makes much more sense now, your time is appreciated. Ill work on trying to understand the docs better as I read through them, sometimes the explanations seem to leave me with more questions than answers as I don't understand all of the terminology being used.